# The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST using laravel ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropzone

i have in an annonces table a multiple images, i want to update multiple images,I just want to send the data to controller but it gives me error : `The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST`.I don't know where the error is.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('filesUpdate','AnnoncesController@filesUpdate')->name('filesUpdate');
```

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function filesUpdate(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->all());
    }
```

**details.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('filesUpdate')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
        {{ csrf_field() }}                            
</form>  
<script type="text/javascript">
            Dropzone.options.dropzone = 
            {
            maxFilesize: 12,
            renameFile: function(file) {
                var images = [];
                $(file).each(function(i){
                  images[i] = file.name;
                  console.log(images);
                }); 
                $.ajax({
                 url:"{{ route('filesUpdate') }}" ,
                 type:'POST',
                 data:{
                    images  : images,
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                 success: function(data, status, xhr){
                  console.log(data, status, xhr);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, msg) {
                  return console.error(xhr, status, msg)
                }})
               //return  images;
            }, 
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function(file, response) 
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(file, response)
            {
               return false;
            }
            };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` is responsible for method spoofing - means it instructs Laravel to use a PUT method for handling the request.

Since your route is defined as POST

```php
Route::post('filesUpdate','AnnoncesController@filesUpdate')->name('filesUpdate');
```

Try removing `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` from the form to get rid of the error - if it works then it means that your form is not getting submitted via ajax

Comment: thx for u answer its give me error message `"Unauthenticated."`

Comment: If `auth` middleware is applied to the Route group containing the route or in Controller's __construct then it requires a logged in user to be able to make the post request

Answer (score 0):

From [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing):

```
Route::match(['put', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});
```